# Как можно реализовать push уведомления без гугл аккаунта?

Tags: android

Подскажите, есть , например, сайт. На сайте есть страница новостей. Есть приложение имеющую информацию о этом сайте. Допустим, новости на сайте обновились, появилось что то новое. Нужно, что бы об этом сообщалось приложению установленному на телефоне в виде push уведомлений. Я рассматривала примеры, но там примеры с google аккаунтом. 
Можно ли такое сделать без google аккаунта?  
Это называется push уведомления? 
Каким образом можно такое реализовать? Через что лучше?
В каком направлении мне двигаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прелесть пушей в том, что инициирует их сервер. Для этого обязателен гугл аккаунт.

Можно сделать и без него, но лишь одним способом - опрашивать сервер самому.
То есть, опрашивать свой сервер на наличие новости или ещё чего-то. Если новости обновились, то получать инфу о новости с сервера и выводить локальный пуш.

Но повторюсь, здесь инициатором запроса выступает клиент, а в случае с нормальными пушами - сервер.

Comment: Открою тайну - пуш на самом то деле инициируется клиентом (операционной системой). И если смотреть совсем сквозь пальцы, то андроидовский пуш - это просто googleTalk, где приложения просто добавляются в список (собственно это все и объясняет многое).

Настоящий пуш я видел только на блекберри. Там он сделан на базе смс.

Comment: @KoVadim, я имел ввиду, что это прозрачно для разработчика. При нормальных пушах мне надо лишь сервис повесить, который будет слушать пуши. В случае же со своим серваком, придётся самому писать таск, чтобы запросы серваку посылать )

Comment: да, для разработчика это очень удобно. Но главное в том, что на клиенте одно подключение, не нужно делать свои костыли на каждый случай.